# Java animation, with key listener

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, keylistener

I tried to make it so that,if I pressed the right/left key, the sprite/Mario would face right/left. If I pressed the right key, he would face right. But for some reason, When I pressed the left key, he won't face left.

Source Code: [First](http://pastebin.com/zzRbAVkg) ,[Second](http://pastebin.com/zHH31ntf)

[Images](http://s1201.photobucket.com/albums/bb356/SubzeroX5/?start=all)

Comment: For better help sooner, post 1 [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) directly in the question, rather than over 250 lines of uncompilable code in 4 classes at a paste bin site.  For the images, feel free to hot-link to some of the images at my [media page](http://pscode.org/media/#image).  Alternately, generate them in code as shown in the [Nested Layout Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271).

Comment: If you call `irFrames()` and `ilFrames()` every time you press an arrow key, you are going to be creating a lot of unnecessary `ImageIcon`s.

Answer (score 2):

"To fire keyboard events, a component *must* have the keyboard focus."—[*How to Write a Key Listener*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which are more flexible and are used by all Swing components.

Comment: This is true for dialog-based apps, but not for games.