# KeyListener doesn't work in JApplet

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I have a class (myKeyListener) that extends keyListener and a I have a JFrame.
I added keyListener to my JFrame and it worked fine. But I had to change it to applet, so I changed JFrame to JInternalFrame and added this to a JApplet. (I didn't change anything else)
now the keyListener doesn't listen. what should I do?

Comment: Either answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728389/java-animation-with-key-listener-problem/6728534#6728534) may prove helpful.

Comment: can you provide an SSCCE please?

Comment: Make sure your component (or some subcomponent of it) actually has the focus.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use [KeyBindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which handle focus issues better and are used by all Swing components.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so heres a solution, instead of adding the keylistener to the applet add it to a JPanel. So act like the JPanel was your JFrame and then just add the keylistener to the JPanel and then add the JPanel to the JApplet and it should work fine! Let me know if that gives you any trouble and ill help you out.